# NSLog not printing out BOOL result to console

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, xcode5, nslog

I have a location app that already successfully asks the user to enable location services, and then can show them their coordinates on a button press as well. So I decided to play around with everything that is available in the CLLocationManager reference provided by xcode.

I decided to setup a bool method called "locationServicesEnabled". It returns a value of YES(1) or NO(0). I declared the method and then went to implement it. I am trying to have NSLog print the bool result out to the console when you open the app.

Here is how I declared the BOOL method in my ViewController.m file:

```
@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled;

@end
```

And here is how I implemented the BOOL method in ViewController.m:

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled{

[self locationServicesEnabled];

NSLog(@"%hhd", self.locationServicesEnabled);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The method `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled` is calling itself. You need to have a variable to hold the boolean value.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Are you saying I need to change it to something like this? +(BOOL)locationServicesEnabled = variableName or do I need to create an object like this +(BOOL)locationServicesEnabled * objectName =

Comment: none of the code you just added is valid objective-c code. As I mentioned in my answer your issue for the BOOL not printing is because of a recursive call to its self. If you have some mis understanding beyond this point please edit the question to provide additional details.

Comment: Voted to close because you have demonstrated no understanding of the problem. You clearly are still in the very early learning stages of Objective-C where you would benefit more from reading a good book on the subject than trying to learn blindly without any prior understanding.

Comment: Jasarien thank you for providing no value what so ever. Coding is the best way to learn coding. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to create an extra method? You could minimize the risk of errors by using already available ones: `NSLog(@"Location services enabled: %d",[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]);`

Comment: I would put the NSLog code you just shared inside the BOOL methods body correct?

Comment: You could do this, yes. But ideally you wouldn't create an extra method at all but just use this line of code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and just made me realize what a dumb mistake I was making. I have no idea why I was even typing out the unneeded BOOL function when I could have just printed it out already. Please clarify though, the reason for this is because the CLLocationManager class and all of it's methods are readily available to me because I imported the CoreLocation.h file into my ViewController.m file correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be the fact that you are calling your function inside its self:

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled
{

     [self locationServicesEnabled]; <- should this be here

     NSLog(@"%hhd", self.locationServicesEnabled);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried getting rid of the method call and it is still not working.

Comment: How and where are you calling this class method ?